# Integrate telegram messenger in Ruby on Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, telegram

Hi all I am currently working on a Ruby on Rails[RoR] 3 project, now I would like to integrate the [telegram](https://telegram.org/) messenger into my existing RoR application.For the past few days I have been looking out on how to integrate it, but I could not find any solutions for that.  Could someone please help me in integrating this messenger in to my rails application?

P.S.
Ruby on rails version is 3.2.19
Ruby version 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

Thanks
Varun Krishna. P

Answer (score 1):

The only thing similar is this gem: https://github.com/platphorm/telegram_rb

But I've tried it without success!!

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using the following gem: https://github.com/ssut/telegram-rb